# How to use enviroment variables for production CI/CD using Github Actions for Nuxt3 App

Tags: firebase, vuejs3, github-actions, cicd, nuxtjs3

I am new to Nuxt, and am using Nuxt 3 for my web app. I have few Firebase secrets that I want to use only in Nuxt server. Locally (Development), the app is working perfectly. I am using a .env file and storing the firebase project config and can access it in the app as mentioned in the details further.

Problem: **CI/CD cannot access the env variables during production build for Nuxt3 app via Github Actions for Firebase.**

**.env**

```
NITRO_PRESET=firebase

# Staging
FIREBASE_APIKEY=**
FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN=**
FIREBASE_PROJECTID=**
FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET=**
FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID=**
FIREBASE_APPID=**
```

In my Nuxt server api
**server/api/testfirebase.get.js**

```
import { db } from './libs/firebase'
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "test"));

    const messages = []
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        messages.push({
            id: doc.id,
            message: doc.data()
        })
    });

    return {
        data: messages
    }
})
```

The firebase initialization file
**server/api/libs/firebase.js**

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

// TODO: Replace the following with your app's Firebase project configuration
// See: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592
const firebaseConfig = 
{

    apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_APIKEY,
  
    authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN,
  
    projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECTID,
  
    storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET,
  
    messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID,
  
    appId: process.env.FIREBASE_APPID
  
  }

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

console.log("THE FIREBASE CONFIG ---------------------------------------------------------------------")
console.log(firebaseConfig)
// Initialize Cloud Firestore and get a reference to the service
const db = getFirestore(app);

export {db};
```

**Output @ localhost:3000/api/testfirebase**

[image]

But, when I deploy it on firebase Hosting, using CI/CD via Github Actions, I cannot access the env variables in my db initialization files ( using `process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECTID` and so on for others )

Here is my yaml file for Github action.
(Sorry it might not be perfect but it works on deploying nuxt server to funtions and frontend to hosting at the same time!)

**staging-deploy.yml**

```
name: Staging Deployment workflow

# Controls when the workflow will run
'on':
  #triggers the workflow whenever a push is made to the milan-dev branch
  push:
    branches:
      - staging

jobs:
  #this workfloe has only one job
  deploy_to_production:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      # this install the dependencies specified in your package.json file into the current workflow
      - name: install dependencies
        # navigates to your functions folder and install the dependencies
        run: npm ci --legacy-peer-deps
      - name: set NITRO_PRESET and run build
        run: NITRO_PRESET=firebase npm run build
        env:
          FIREBASE_APIKEY: ${{ secrets.STAGING_FIREBASE_APIKEY }}
          FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN: ${{ secrets.STAGING_FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN }}
          FIREBASE_DATABASEURL: ${{ secrets.STAGING_FIREBASE_DATABASEURL }}
          FIREBASE_PROJECTID: ${{ secrets.STAGING_FIREBASE_PROJECTID }}
          FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET: ${{ secrets.STAGING_FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET }}
          FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID: ${{ secrets.STAGING_FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID }}
          FIREBASE_APPID: ${{ secrets.STAGING_FIREBASE_APPID }}
          FIREBASE_MEASUREMENTID: ${{ secrets.STAGING_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENTID }}
        # If your firebase cloud functions project uses firebase-admin 
        # you need to create a config file used to initialize your project
        # the below task creates a config.json file in your functions directory
      - name: create config json
        uses: jsdaniell/create-json@1.1.2
        id: create-config-json
        with:
          name: 'config.json'
          json: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}'
          dir: '.output/server'
        # The below task uses the w9jds/firebase-action@master action with the appropriate argument 
        # to deploy your firebase cloud functions.
      - name: deploy functions to production
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
        with:
          args: use staging && firebase deploy --config staging.firebase.json -P staging
        env:
          GCP_SA_KEY: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}
          FIREBASE_APIKEY: ${{ secrets.STAGING_FIREBASE_APIKEY }}
          FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN: ${{ secrets.STAGING_FIREBASE_AUTHDOMAIN }}
          FIREBASE_DATABASEURL: ${{ secrets.STAGING_FIREBASE_DATABASEURL }}
          FIREBASE_PROJECTID: ${{ secrets.STAGING_FIREBASE_PROJECTID }}
          FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET: ${{ secrets.STAGING_FIREBASE_STORAGEBUCKET }}
          FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID: ${{ secrets.STAGING_FIREBASE_MESSAGINGSENDERID }}
          FIREBASE_APPID: ${{ secrets.STAGING_FIREBASE_APPID }}
          FIREBASE_MEASUREMENTID: ${{ secrets.STAGING_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENTID }}
```

Here is a picture of my cloud console not getting the env variables which I am logging in my **server/api/libs/firebase.js** file

[image]

The official Nuxt3 [documentation](https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-runtime-config#using-the-env-file) Mentions:

> Any environment variables set within .env file are accessed using process.env in the Nuxt app during development and build/generate.
> In production runtime, you should use platform environment variables and .env is not used.

**Also could anyone explain this line further `In production runtime, you should use platform environment variables and .env is not used.`**

I would appreciate anyone having a solution and anyone reading through the question (sorry for being so lengthy, just trying to be as detailed as possile). Let me know if you want more details, I can edit it further.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the secrets to your GitHub repository?

To do so, navigate to Settings --> Security --> Secrets and variables --> Actions --> New repository secret. This will allow your GitHub actions .yaml file to access the secrets you've declared under **env**.

Comment: Yeah, I have the secrets in the github actions. I also double checked the names. :(

Comment: @MilanLakhani Thanks for confirming. Let's try something else...you are declaring env variables in 2 steps ("set NITRO_PRESET and run build" and "deploy functions to production."). Step "create config json" doesn't have any env variables defined, even though you are trying to access '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}'. Try hoisting up your env variables to the top of the file so they are defined for all steps.  Here is GitHub documentation w/example: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#defining-environment-variables-for-a-single-workflow